# how to clear cache of urllib3.PoolManager?

Tags: python, python-requests, get, urllib3

I am using `urllib3.PoolManager` for creating a request and sending it. this is my code:

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager(
            timeout=10,
        )
response=http.request('GET','example.com')
print(response.headers)
```

The output is as follows:

```
HTTPHeaderDict({'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/10.0', 'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'X-Powered-By-Plesk': 'PleskWin', 'Date': 'Tue, 16 Aug 2022 06:57:53 GMT', 'Content-Length': '5807'})
```

After that, I used python `requests` instead of `urllib3` as follows:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('example.com')
print(response.headers)
```

The output is as follows:

```
{'Cache-Control': 'private', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Vary': 'Accept-Encoding,Accept-Encoding', 'Server': 'Microsoft-IIS/10.0', 'Set-Cookie': 'ASP.NET_SessionId=2tygffzylqwnw3spoavb4lbe; path=/; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax', 'X-AspNet-Version': '4.0.30319', 'X-Powered-By': 'ASP.NET', 'X-Powered-By-Plesk': 'PleskWin', 'Date': 'Tue, 16 Aug 2022 06:57:55 GMT', 'Content-Length': '40682'}
```

As can be seen, when I use python requests, the response header is including `Set-Cookie`, but, when I used urllib3, the response header does not have `Set-Cookie`.

What is the problem? I need the `Set-Cookie` varible in the `urllib3` response header.

Comment: One of the benefits of using the requests library is the support for cookies. It is based on the urllib3 library, but adds a lot of extra content, like cookies.

Comment: @user56700 So There are no solutions?

Comment: Not as far as I know.